# Android view visibility after screen on

Tags: android, androidx

I am using `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2` and facing `visibility` issue with child layout inside `FrameLayout`. I am using a loader in `FrameLayout` that get visible only when data is downloading and its visibility is set to `GONE` when its done. The problem is when I switch off the screen and turns it on again, the visibility of loader is automatically set to visible.

I have tried to debug the code also without any luck. There is only one way to set its visibility that is inside data function which is only called in `onCreate` event. Switching on the screen and returning to the app only triggers `onStart` event which is empty.

I have updated the lib to latest 1.1, but it have more visibility bugs. Is someone else also facing this issue and any temporary workaround suggestion?

Comment: Code you provide the code that you are working on?

Answer (score -1):

Your activity might be getting destroyed on screen off, and may be getting re-started after waking the device.

Also, `onStart` isn't the only **lifeCycle** method that gets triggered on returning to app.

Comment: Like I said I have debug the app and layout is only setup in `onStart` event. Visibility of loader is also set to `GONE` by default. So, if activity is restarted then the loader should be `GONE`.

Comment: Then, try updating the post with the code snippet, because guessing the issue without seeing the actual code got me a downvote.